# Use outputTemplate in HTTP sink for Exception logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore, serilog-exceptions

Trying to send logs to remote http server using `serilog-sinks-http` and `Serilog.Exceptions` is required to get exception details.

In `Serilog.Exceptions` documents it required outputTemplate to be set to `{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception} {Properties:j}` to work.

Couldn't find outputTemplate parameter in HTTP Sink, now logs look similar to:

```
03/06/2024 13:00:00 +03:30 [Error] Error occured
System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero.
   at logexample.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\repos\logexample\Program.cs:line 29
```

Also innerException is needed to be placed in logs (innerException itself may contain another innerException which all are needed).

Comment: There are fundamentally two type of sinks - text-based (console, file) and structured (all others). OutputTemplate string is applied only to first type of them. HttpSink just sends LogEvent occured as `application/json` content. So, no need for you to set up template for `serilog-sinks-http`.

Comment: Then how should I get exception details to send via HTTP sink ?

Comment: Check out [sample code](https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/serilog-sinks-http-sample-dotnet-core/blob/0c585c0f06ca6e4e936151a3b6958c44388711f4/log-server/Controllers/LogEventsController.cs). I did not check for the case with ExceptionDetails, but basic usage puts Exception text as part of [RenderedMessage](https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/serilog-sinks-http-sample-dotnet-core/blob/0c585c0f06ca6e4e936151a3b6958c44388711f4/log-server/Controllers/LogEvent.cs#L9) property.

Comment: I believe details should be part of the message too.